# Why not place if __name__ == '__main__' at the beginning of the module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is it standard in Python to have the `main()` function and the if `__name__ == '__main__'` check at the end of the block of code? It also seems standard for the abstraction of the functions to follow the same pattern upwards. What I mean is that the definition of the function to be executed by `main()` is above the `main()` and the definition of the functions inside that are above and so on..

That seems odd because when one opens the module to read the code, it ends up starting with low-level code and moves up to higher level functions. Isn't it hard to grasp what the module is doing that way?

Why not do the alternative? Have the if `__name__` check at the top followed by the `main()` function, and so on. This way, one quickly glances at what the `main()` function does and understands what the code is about.

Comment: You can't call `main()` before it is defined. And `main` cannot call other functions before they are defined.

Comment: If you would have tested what re writing about you would have found the answer rather quickly.

Comment: Voting to reopen the question, as it's definitly NOT "opinion-based" - the answer is totally factual and technical.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't call `main()` before it is defined. And `main` cannot call other functions before they are defined.

Example 1:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()

def main():
    print("Hello")
```

This will error because `main` hasn't been defined yet at the point where you try and execute it.

Example 2:

```
def main():
    hello()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()

def hello():
    print("Hello")
```

This will error because `main()` is executed and tries to call `hello` before it is defined.

The `if __name__=='__main__':` which contains the call to `main()` works best at the end of the file so that everything that it needs has been defined before it is reached.

Where you put the `main` definition itself is more flexible, but putting it at the end (just before the `if __name__=='__main__':` block that calls it) makes as much sense as anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of an `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard is to prevent a module from having side-effects when it's imported.

The fact that it is a module rather than a script implies that it will normally be used by other code importing the definitions from it, not executed directly. So given that, it makes sense that the functions, classes and constants appear first in the source code, since those are what users of the module will be importing (and hence, what they might want to see the source of).

So even if the code guarded by `if __name__ == '__main__':` doesn't rely on the definitions in the module already having been evaluated (which would be unusual), this part of the code is usually the *least* important to the users of the module, so it doesn't belong at the start of the file.

Comment: Also, if `if __name__ == '__main__': main()` was at the beginning of the file, `main()` wouldn't yet be defined at that point.